# Can i make a relationship between two relationships in the database?

Tags: database-design, erd, orm

I am making a database system where there are patients, doctors, categories and medical records.

- doctor and patient has a relationship called `treatments` ( many-to-many )
- patient and a relationship with medical record called `patient-records` ( one-to-many )
- medical record and categories has relationship called `record-category` (many-to-many)

My questions:

How do I include the details and information of the medical record in the `treatment` relationship?  Should I make a joined query and get the details of record from the patient?

My goal is to create a full record for the patient where all their history, diagnoses, and treatments are available as a sheet or web page.

Comment: Please edit your question so there's only one question. Right now it's running the risk of being closed as "too broad". Which alternative design to take is going to be a matter of opinion; we can only help you with the technical possibilities. My answer shows a direction you might be able to go.

Comment: @Colin'tHart you mean i remove the second question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can make a new table which has foreign keys to both `treatments` and `patient-records`.

But be careful either in your model or in your code that you don't associate patient-records from a different patient with the patient associated with the treatment... using natural keys is one way to solve this:

- `treatments` has a primary or unique key (`doctor`, `patient`) -- Doctor and Patient can be surrogate keys -- and both of these are foreign keys to `doctor` and `patient`, respectively.
- `patient-records` has a primary or unique key (`patient`, `medical-record`) -- similarly, these are both foreign keys.
- your new table has a primary or unique key (`doctor`, `patient`, `medical-record`) -- and there are two foreign keys: one on (`doctor`, `patient`) to `treatments`, and the other on (`patient`,`medical-record`) to `medical-records`.

Comment: ok , does that makes the relationship between `treatments` and `patient-records` many-to-many with a new table or relationship between them?